# How to rotate keys for plaintext in DB encrypted by RSA?

Tags: rsa

I have encrypted plaintext with an RSA public key. It is stored in a database. This public key will be encrypted by another key with a different encryption algorithm. What does key rotation look like here? How would I rotate the keys that are directly encrypting the plaintext.

Comment: What does key rotation mean for you? By the way, RSA is not good for encryption.

Comment: ECC for encryption. Key rotation as you understand it. I see conflicting information online.

Comment: @tiotolstoy there's very little context of what's encrypted, how or why. Can you add context, like a threat model? Data field limitations, etc?